# worklight http adapter authentication issue with apache

Tags: apache, ibm-mobilefirst, basic-authentication

I'm working on a mobile prof-of-concept using IBM's Worklight (6.1) to retrieve info via HTTP server (Apache) running on a mainframe (z/OS). I'm using the HTTP adapter procedure to log-on and retrieve data but I so far no success logging on via Worklight HTTP adapter. If I open a browser and provide the 'user:password' headers, the log-in is successful but if I try it via Worklight procedure, the '401 authorization required' error is returned. The HTTP server error log shows:

> .. (139)EDC5139I Operation not permitted. (errno2=0x0BE800DB): SAF
>   authentication failure for "/cgi-bin/itil_v11_main.sh": SAFRunAs
>   failure on switching SAF UID from Authorization header using
>   %%CLIENT%%  .. user (\xe1\xcb: authentication failure for
>   "/cgi-bin/itil_v11_main.sh": Password Mismatch

That 'password mismatch' may suggest the 'headers' are not correct? Here's the procedure:

```
var user_id = 'userid';
var user_psw = 'userpassword';
var loginstring ;
var base64= new com.worklight.customcode.Base64Encoding();

function getITIL() {

    loginstring = base64.encode(user_id+':'+user_psw);  

    var path = '/cgi-bin/itil_v11_main.sh';

    var input = {
        method : 'get',
        headers : {         
            'Authorization' : 'Basic ' + loginstring    
        },
        returnedContentType : 'html',
        path : path
    };

    return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you've implemented it correctly, however the complaint is on the password, which in your case originates from `var base64= new com.worklight.customcode.Base64Encoding();`.

Because you do not supply the code that you are using in said class, it's difficult to say what the error is, but that is where you should look at for the cause of your error.

You'll need to provide the class's implementation in order to further debug the question.